# Piping JSON to mongoimport

Tags: python, json, mongodb, ubuntu, pipe

I've been looking around on the internet but couldn't find anything.

My question is simple. Can I pipe JSON to mongoimport?
My goal? Doing this stuff in real time with one command without interuptions (and without extra stuff I need to install).

Example:

```
python twitterTweets.py | mongoimport --type json --db test1337 --collection tweets
```

Is this possible?

If I just put the output of twitterTweets.py in a .json file, I am able to import it into MongoDB using (code below is already working):

```
mongoimport --type json --db test1337 --collection tweets < /directoryHere/stream.json
```

==========================

Some more background info:

- When I throw the upper command, one of my terminals show:

  `(1 connection now open)`
- When I enter `mongo` after that and type `show dbs`, the new document is not showing.
- When I throw the second command and than the first one, the document isn't growing.
- When entering the first command I'm not getting any errors. Instead it says:

  `[enterDateHere] test1337.tweets 0.0 B
  [enterDateHere] test1337.tweets 4.0 KB
  [enterDateHere] test1337.tweets 8.0 KB`

That tells me that there is something happening!

Comment: What about doing it the other way around and inserting the data from you Python script into the DB using Python instead of mongoimport? You can access a MongoDB using `pymongo` or `mongoengine` for example.

Comment: This is certainly possible: https://sandalov.org/blog/1933/. Likely some issue in syntax or something

Comment: Oh well, I installed pymongo and it's working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not piping but still an one-liner:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --type json --db diameter --collection msg --file <(tshark -r bzz.snoop -Tjson)
```

So in your example:

```
mongoimport --type json --db test1337 --collection tweets --file <(python twitterTweets.py)
```

Jarek